# Android AOSP build fails with "Communication error with Jack server"

Tags: android, android-source

I have successfully sync the source code of android-7.1.2_r11 from AOSP. Now, I got the following error while I was trying to build the source code. Anyone can tell me how I can fix it, and finish a successful build? Thanks much in advance.

Please see the attached screenshot for detailed build error.

BTW, my ubuntu version is 16.04. OpenJDK version is 1.8.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Y9G.png)

error log:

Communication error with Jack server (56). Try 'jack-diagnose'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

make failed to build some targets (02:17:10 (hh:mm:ss))

Comment: Try "make -j32 showcommands " when building . It will show you the exact line where the error occurs .Post that error here .

Comment: Hi, @khetanrajesh, I did "make -j32 showcommands" like you suggested, and got the error log, please see the updated edit. Thanks.

Comment: Hi , do you have enough RAM  ? if not try disabling the JACK server .    Alos try stop and starting the JACK server .(  jack-admin kill-server  , jack-admin start-server )

Comment: Hi, @khetanrajesh, I only have 3GB ram. Will that be a issue? Besides, to disable the JACK server, do you mean type ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK=false in the terminal before make? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you should have minimum of 8GB RAM . Check this 
 https://source.android.com/source/requirements

Comment: Oh... I see. So sad... Thank you so much for your explanation. @khetanrajesh

Answer (score 3):

If its ssl error, edit java.security file under /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/
Remove TLSv1, TLSv1.1 from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
Restart the jack server:
cd /prebuilts/sdk/tools/

```
cd prebuilts/sdk/tools
touch jack
./jack-admin kill-server
./jack-admin start-server
mm -j32 showcommands
./jack-admin install-server jack-launcher.jar jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Restart jack or reboot your machine

In your source tree root:

```
$ prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin stop-server 2>&1 > /dev/null
$ prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin cleanup-server 2>&1 > /dev/null
$ prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

You might want to do that multiple times to ensure it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that Jack builds were deprecated in March 2017, you should move to the latest Android Studio when possible: https://source.android.com/setup/jack | http://archive.is/IKUGj

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @khetanrajesh

i just did -

```
$ prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin kill-server 
$ prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server
```

Now it works fine.